# JQuery : How to create dynamic pie chart with input range slider

Tags: jquery, plugins, charts, pie-chart

I am beginner to this, I'm trying to search better plugin for creating Pie chart that has a input range controller and dynamically change the slice when sliding the input range. But its hard for me to understand some of them.

Here is an accurate example of what I need. But this one seems not working for me

http://fiddle.jshell.net/CfXe3/51/light/

Is there any plugin that similar to that?